# Norm equivalence of a vector norm and its induced matrix norm using compactness argument

Tags: normed-spaces, compactness

I have a theorem in my book on matrix computations that states the following:

A vector norm and its induced matrix norm satisfy the inequality:

$\|Ax\|\leq \|A\|$$\|x\|$ where A $\in R^{nxn}$ and x $\in R^n$.

The book states that equality holds, "if and only if x is a vector for which the maximum magnification is attained. (That such a vector exists is actually not obvious. It follows from a compactness argument that works because $R^n$ is a finite-dimensional space. We omit the argument.)"

I am interested in knowing how I would go about showing that equality holds if x is a vector for which max magnification is attained. This is not a homework problem; however, I would like to know for my upcoming exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the closed unit ball $\overline{B}$ is compact. The function $f(x) = \|Ax\|$ is continuous, and continuous functions attain their maximum on a compact set, ie, there exists $x_0 \in \overline{B}$ such that $f(x_0) = \max_{x \in \overline{B}} f(x)$. In particular, $\|A x_0 \| = \max_{x \in \overline{B}} \|Ax\|$.

The induced norm is defined as $\|A\| = \max_{x \in \overline{B}} \|A x\|$, and the above remark shows that this is attained for some $x_0$.

Comment: Isn't the induced defined as the supremum normally ?

Comment: I've seen it as both sup and max.

Comment: It is, but since we are talking about finite dimensional spaces...

Comment: Would this work for the eigenvectors of an symmetric matrix as well? Could you take the eigenvector, say $v_{max}$ corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of a matrix A and show that:

 $ \|Av_{max}\|$ = max$\|Ax\|$ for $x\in$ orthogonal set of eigenvectors.

Comment: @AnnMarie: (1) Since the above is true for any matrix, it is certainly true for symmetric matrices. (2) Your suggested characterization will work if the norm is the Euclidean norm, but not for any norm in general.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a little careful here. A norm that satisfies $||Ax|| \leq ||A||||x||$ is called a submultiplicative norm. Not all induced norms are submultiplicative. Take for example the max norm $||A||_{max}=max\{|a_{ij}|\}$. This is not submultiplicative. A good book for all of this is Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson. See here [http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Analysis-Roger-A-Horn/dp/0521386322](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521386322)

Comment: every induced norm is submultiplicative, your example is not a induced norm !

Comment: and furthermore a norm is called submultiplicative if $$\| A \cdot B\| \leq \| A \|\cdot \|B\|$, were $A,B$ are matrices, the OP ask for the norm to be consistent that is something else

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we can assume $x$ to be in the boundary of  unit sphere $B$, as this inequality is invariant for scaling as the norms are homogene.
The right hand side is 
\begin{align*}
\|A\|\cdot \|x\|&= \sup_{v\in \partial B} \frac{\| Av \|}{\|v\|} \cdot \|x\|\\
&=\sup_{v\in \partial B} \|A \cdot v\|
\end{align*}
It is trivial that 
$$\|A\cdot x \|\leq \sup_{v \in \partial B} \|A\cdot v\|$$

As the supremum is always greater than $\|A\cdot x\|$ if $x$ is not the maximum, the equality hold iff the maximum is attached at $x$

Comment: Thanks, Dominic. Your explanation is very helpful as well.

Comment: @AnnMarie glad i can help, once you reach 15 reputation, you can upovte the answers :)