# Norm inequality for matrix and vector $\|ABx\|_p \leq \|A\|_p\|Bx\|_p$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

When I read a lecture note, it says

$$\|ABx\|_p \leq \|A\|_p\|Bx\|_p$$

1. $A$, $B$ are matrices with appropriate dimension.
2. $x$ is a vector

My questions are

1. Why does this inequality hold?     This includes matrix norm and vector norm.
2. Under what conditions, the following holds?   $$\|ABx\|_p = \|A\|_p\|Bx\|_p=\|Bx\|_p$$

I believe $A$ has to be an orthogonal matrix, i.e., $A^TA = AA^T = I$ at least so $\|A\|_p=1$.

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably ignore $B$ here: $v=Bx$ will itself be a vector, making the inequality $\|Av\|_p \leq \|A\|_p \|v\|_p$.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Compatible_norms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compatible norms, including induced norms (as $\|\cdot\|_p)$ we have $\|Ay\|\leq \|A\|\  \|y\|$ in your case $y=Bx$. This inequality follows from the definition of $\|A\|=\sup\left\lbrace \frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}:y\neq 0\right\rbrace$. For the equality, you need that the vector $y$ maximizes the quantity $\frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}$, which is not always an easy task. Check this question for more information [Norm equivalence of a vector norm and its induced matrix norm using compactness argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340989/norm-equivalence-of-a-vector-norm-and-its-induced-matrix-norm-using-compactness)

Comment: Not for any norm... for compatible norms (which include induced norms). There are other possible matrix norms...

Comment: @ClementC. It's true, I have updated!